# Revoke the permission to run an application from an unidentified developer

Tags: macos, catalina, gatekeeper

Few weeks ago I've installed a CLI application from Homebrew that wasn't signed or notarised (what's Apple calls from an "unidentified developer").

To run this application I've followed [the well know steps from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh40616/mac) and called it a day.

Now I want to revoke this exception to be able to test the new version of the same CLI application that will come signed and notarised by the developer.

I've tried to follow the instruction from posts that suggest the change Gatekeeper rules using `spctl` like [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332910/how-to-revoke-permission-given-in-system-prefs-security-privacy-allow) without success.

It looks like the rules managed using `spctl` are not involved in this context, because I've tried to do:

```
$ spctl --reset-default

$ spctl --list > list.before.txt
```

and then I've authorised the app to run using System Preferences > Security & Privacy > 'Allow'

```
$ spctl --list > list.after.txt
```

and after run a compare between the two:

```
$ diff list.before.txt list.after.txt
(no differences)
```

The CLI app continue to run no matter what I do with the `spctl` utility.

How can I revert the permission to run to this unidentified developer's CLI app?

Comment: May I know the name of CLI application? I can try to help you with this ?

Comment: Yep, I've testing https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/arduino-cli, currently not signed or notarised.

Comment: But I'm having the same issue with other CLI apps as well, such as `jtool` from Homebrew (via cask).

I'd love to know how the OS saves these exceptions and how to revert this choice later and be able to test the code-signed and notarised version of the same application later from a clean state.

So thank you @Udhy for your interest, if you have any experience to share on this, please share it here! :-D

Answer (score 1):

The permission is actually persisted by removing a specific attribute from the file's metadata.

You mentioned in comments that you were having this problem with jtool from Homebrew Cask. When you install that program, you'll see the attributes listed by running:

```
xattr -l /usr/local/bin/jtool
```

It will display something like this:

```
com.apple.quarantine: 0291;5df6a9fa;Homebrew\x20Cask;1E71AF5A-2719-340C-9A49-DDB4D10769BE
```

You can remove that attribute with the following command:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /usr/local/bin/jtool
```

Now you won't get the prompt.

Add the attribute again to restore the prompt:

```
xattr -w com.apple.quarantine "0291;5df6a9fa;Homebrew\x20Cask;1E71AF5A-2719-340C-9A49-DDB4D10769BE" /usr/local/bin/jtool
```

Comment: @david-anderson Why add a dot to the end of the answer?

Comment: When code is long enough, a scrollbar is added to the webpage. When I view this webpage, I see a scrollbar below `xattr -w com.apple.quarantine "0291;5df6a9fa;Homebrew\x20Cask;1E71AF5A-2719-340C-9A49-DDB4D10769BE" /usr/local/bin/jtool`. If I reload the webpage, then the scrollbar stops working. One way to fix this problem is to add text after the code entry. I used a dot. I changed this to a nonbreaking space which will not appear to the viewer.

Comment: Really odd! - I didn't see that here (using Safari), so I guess it must be a problem with some other browsers. Nice fix with the non-breaking space - makes it look much less weird :-)

Comment: First, @jksoegaard thank you for writing your answer! 

Unfortunately this is not the same prompt I was looking to restore. The `com.apple.quarantine` it's an extended attribute added to downloaded files by applications that download some binaries/applications from the Internet. 

This is done by Apple own software (such as Safari web browser) and even 3rd party software (like the Transmission BitTorrent client https://github.com/transmission/transmission/blob/fa504fb27f2840561dbec20bda55a99d16a9808f/macosx/Torrent.m#L1864).

Comment: The situation I'm trying to recreate it's the one described on https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491 in the section named "If you see a warning message and can't install an app.".

It's a perfectly legit message because from the system, the binary it's not signed or notarized, and I want back that situation to test the new signed binary (and of course, I also want to understand how the security mechanism is working for the sake of it ^^).

Comment: @zmoog Yes, I'm aware that's how the extended attribute works - however, you might not know that this is ALSO done by HomeBrew. I.e. if you install jtool from cask via HomeBrew, which is what you wrote you had problems with, then this quarantine attribute is set - and I do get a warning prompt when I open it. However, if I remove the attribute, as described in my answer, the warning prompt goes away. So if your problem is the jtool program as described, then this is actually a solution for that. If you're on Catalina and the program you want to test with is not notarized, then yes, this might

Comment: [...] then yes, this might not be the solution for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not, and  I don't get the “application downloaded from the internet” message when I run CLI applications (or, at least, now I don't remember seeing that), it seems that the quarantine xattrs only affects the GUI apps.

Comment: UPDATE: I was wrong, the “application downloaded from the internet” shows up also for CLI applications. ☺️